# QTP/UFT change or modify URL during test execution

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, hp-uft

I have an UFT script, in the second action, i need change the URL DURING test execution, because need to permissions obtained in login in first URL for work in second URL. Don't work in a new sheet or window.
Somebody can help me?
This is my code:

```
'Int user
Browser("Inicio").Page("Inicio").WebEdit("userid").Set "user"
Browser("Inicio").Page("Inicio").WebButton("Entrar").Click

Wait 3
'Int Pass
Browser("Inicio").Page("Inicio").WebEdit("password").Set "pass"
Browser("Inicio").Page("Inicio").WebButton("Aceptar").Click
Wait 10

' Change URL for work:
'In this point, i need help
```

Comment: You have not given any clear indication of what you are trying to do, or what you have done.  The question will likely be closed down very soon if you do not provide the information needed to be able to help.  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you asking. What my guess is

1. You need to login which you have done already.
2. Get current URL from browser so that you can get a particular string from URL to put it in another URL

If so, then you can use *GetROProperty* of browser page. So code would be like

```
Browser("Inicio").Page("Inicio"). GetROProperty ("URL")
```

Comment: Let me explain: In the UFT recording configuration, I indicated a URL to work with;

Comment: Let me explain: In the UFT recording settings, I indicated a URL to work:
P.E. https://myPage1/
But after entering this and signing, I need to change the URL with the authorization credentials of the web page where I signed.
P.E. https://myPage2/
To continue working on this new page.
It does not help me to open a new browser or new sheet because it does not keep my authorization credentials.
I hope you have made me understand @Ashish Waghmare